# Merge Array data based on id

Tags: php

**Raw data**

```
Array
  (
    [0] => Array
      (
        [bet_id] => 7
        [agent_id] => 2
        [bet_type] => 1
        [amount] => 0
        [name] => ethan
       )

     [1] => Array
          (
            [bet_id] => 7
            [agent_id] => 2
            [bet_type] => 3
            [amount] => 0
            [name] => ethan
           )

      [2] => Array
             (
               [bet_id] => 7
               [agent_id] => 4
               [bet_type] => 1
               [amount] => 2
               [name] => alex
              )

       [3] => Array
               (
                 [bet_id] => 7
                 [agent_id] => 4
                 [bet_type] => 4
                 [amount] => 100
                 [name] => alex
               ) 
    )
```

I get stuck in the logic thinking to separate the above data. The above array will loop all the users data, there have 2 users here. How can I merge it into 2 arrays based on agentId. It will become as below.

```
Array
     ( 
      [0] => Array 
         (
            [agent_id] => 2
            [name] => ethan
            [1] => 2    //bettype & amount
            [3] => 0    //bettype & amount
            [bet_id] => 7                       
          )                                           
     [1] => Array 
          (
             [agent_id] => 4
             [name] => alex
             [1] => 0     //bettype & amount
             [4] => 100    //bettype & amount
             [bet_id] => 7                       
          )
     )
```

**Note: the only different data which is agent_id, bet_type, and amount. Other data will be the same.**

Comment: have you tried to use an usual foreach?

Comment: Are you sure that using the bet type as the key and amount as the value is a good solution?

Comment: erm, still thinking the better way, get stuck :(.

Comment: @MMMM Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). Show us the source code you have tried and explain how they fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

putting `bet_type` as key and `amount` as value makes your data structure looks bad, but lets make it

```
$result = [];
foreach($data as $user) {
    $found = -1;
    for($i = 0; $i<count($result); $i++) {
        if($result[$i]["agent_id"] == $user["agent_id"]) {
            $found = $i;
            break;
        }
    }
    // if not found, create new
    if($found == -1) {
        $result[] = [
            "agent_id" => $user["agent_id"],
            "name" => $user["name"],
            "bet_id" => $user["bet_id"],
            $user["bet_type"] => $user["amount"]
        ];
    } else {
        $result[$i][$user["bet_type"]] = $user["amount"];
    }
}
```

`$data` is your array and the output will be like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [agent_id] => 2
            [name] => ethan
            [bet_id] => 7
            [1] => 0
            [3] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [agent_id] => 4
            [name] => alex
            [bet_id] => 7
            [1] => 2
            [4] => 100
        )

)
```

I suggest yo change the `bet_type` position by putting them on child array like this

```
$result = [];
foreach($data as $user) {
    $found = -1;
    for($i = 0; $i<count($result); $i++) {
        if($result[$i]["agent_id"] == $user["agent_id"]) {
            $found = $i;
            break;
        }
    }
    // if not found, create new
    if($found == -1) {
        $result[] = [
            "agent_id" => $user["agent_id"],
            "name" => $user["name"],
            "bet_id" => $user["bet_id"],
            "details" => [
                $user["bet_type"] => $user["amount"]
            ]
        ];
    } else {
        $result[$i]["details"][$user["bet_type"]] = $user["amount"];
    }
}
```

this will make your data easier to see

the output will like this

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [agent_id] => 2
            [name] => ethan
            [bet_id] => 7
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 0
                    [3] => 0
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [agent_id] => 4
            [name] => alex
            [bet_id] => 7
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 2
                    [4] => 100
                )

        )

)
```